# Do eigenvalues and eigenvectors completely characterize the behavior of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand that eigenvalues describe the action of the matrix upon eigenvectors. And if the eigenvectors form a basis of the input space (RHS) of matrix $A$, we can fully describe how $A$ affects a given input vector $x$.

But what more can we say? For example, if I give you a set of eigenvalues and eigenvectors, does that fully describe what the matrix $A$ does? Why not just use eigenvalues and eigenvectors then instead of the full matrix?

Any reading to further material would be great as well.

Comment: Since eigendecomposition does not lose information regarding the matrix, eigenvectors and eigenvalues can indeed be used in place of the matrix. Also, the number of "free" parameters in the matrix $A$ and in the eigendecomposition are the same.

Comment: Eigenvalues and eigenvectors seem like a dream, until you try adding matrices (or even multiplication can be tricky). Then you're glad that you know the components. Like with most other things that can be expressed in a number of forms, different forms of the same matrix will be useful in different situations.

Comment: Well if you told me that a matrix had characteristic polynomial $x^5$ and that its eigenspace had dimension $2$ that would not be enough to tell the whole story. There are examples with minimal polynomial $x^3$ and with minimal polynomial $x^4$. [Exercise for reader.]

Answer (score 0):

You will find greater clarity on these concepts in a standard undergraduate course on linear algebra.

The eigenvalues of a matrix play an important role in decomposing the matrix into the Jordan normal form. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form

The eigenvalues of a matrix are also relevant to the characteristic polynomial of a matrix. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial

The kernel of a matrix is basically the eigenspace associated to the eigenvalue $0$.

So eigenvectors and eigenvalues are of course very important.

But not every matrix is diagonalisable. Also, even if two different matrices are diagonalisable, it doesn't mean that there is a single change of basis that diagonalises both of them. This is why the structure of matrices goes beyond just their action on eigenvectors.